# SonarLint's Exlude From Analysis does not work

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sonarqube, sonarlint

- I have installed SonarLint in Visual Studio 2017.  (version 4.27.022695)
- Enabled full solution anlysis.
- SonarLint is connected to SonarQube Server (it has downloaded new rulesets from server)
- Then i enabled `Exclude from analyzing` option on Test Projects

  - Right Click on Test Project ->SonarLint Connected Mode-> Exclude from Analysis
  - Which adds `<SonarQubeExclude>True</SonarQubeExclude>` into csproj
  - then i re-build the whole solution.

**Issue**
In visual studio i still see warnings from Test Project.

I have also tried setting the test project as SonarQube test project. So my csproj file has two entries now

```
<SonarQubeExclude>True</SonarQubeExclude>

<SonarQubeTestProject>True</SonarQubeTestProject>
```

However, upon building the solution in VS, I still see Sonar's warnings and information from Test project

Answer (score 0):

looks like currently its not possible

[reference](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarlints-exclude-from-analysis-does-not-work/33685/2)